# Obj-C - Display correct data for each cell from corresponding array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my tableView, I'm trying to display a certain type of cell for every dictionary in which swapvalue is equal to 0. That being said, for some reason, the below code ONLY grabs the value of the first dictionary in my array (***AKA:*** the value of swapvalue in the first dictionary is 0, and thus, my table displays all cells as if the arrays that follow also have swapvalue  0 - even though they do not). How can I change this so that each cell is grabbing swapvalue from its corresponding dictionary? I suspect it has something to do with indexPath.row, but I'm not sure how to correct this?

```
 - (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {


        if ([self.messageDataFriends count] > 0 ) {


            NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];


            DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
            [session setUser:userDictInfo];


            [session user];


            NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageDataFriends objectForKey:@"uid2"];

            NSString *myID = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];


            NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

            NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", myID];

            NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", myID];

            NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

            NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2,]];

            NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4,]];

            NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2]];

            NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];


        return [filtered count];

            }


        else  {


            NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];

            DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
            [session setUser:userDictInfo];


            [session user];

            NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageData objectForKey:@"uid"];

            NSString *myID = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];


            NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

            NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", myID];

            NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", myID];

            NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

            NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2,]];

            NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4,]];

            NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2]];

            NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];


          return [filtered count];


         }
    }



         - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {

                NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.section];

                id swapvalue = data[@"swapvalue"];
                NSLog(@"SWAP VALUE %@", swapvalue);

            if ([neighbours count] > 0 && [swapvalue isEqualToString: @"0"]) {

 static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";


        SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];


          NSString *targetedUser = [self.messageData objectForKey:@"uid"];


          NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];

          DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
          [session setUser:userDictInfo];


          [session user];


          NSString *myID = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];

          NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

         NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", myID];

          NSPredicate *p3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid contains[cd] %@", myID];

          NSPredicate *p4 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"targetuser contains[cd] %@", targetedUser];

          NSCompoundPredicate *pIntermediary1 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p1, p2,]];

          NSCompoundPredicate * pIntermediary2 = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[p3, p4,]];

          NSCompoundPredicate *pFinal = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pIntermediary1, pIntermediary2]];

         NSArray *filtered = [self.messages filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pFinal];


          NSLog(@"WAT IS HERE 2 %@", filtered);

          NSString *userName = filtered[indexPath.row][@"first name"];
          cell.sendingUser.text = userName;

          NSString *messageBody = filtered[indexPath.row][@"body"];
          cell.messageDisplayed.text = messageBody;

          NSString *timeReceived = filtered[indexPath.row][@"published at"];
          cell.timeStamp.text = timeReceived;

      }

        return cell;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, messages is an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary of arrays. You talk about the "First array in my dictionary", but that's wrong. You only have 1 array.

The code you posted would crash if the data was not an array of dictionaries.

I suggest logging your `messages` structure to see what it really contains.

### EDIT:

The code you posted in your edit is a mess. You should **not** be building predicates and sorting stuff in response to any of the table view data source methods. You should build a data model at the time you invoke the table view and then leave it alone.

If you have a single section table view, you should return 1 in response to the numberOfSections call, and the data for all your cells would come out of a single array.

Your numberOfRowsInSection call should just look up the number of items in the array for that section.

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method should fetch a data item from the array for that row in that (one) section and use it to populate the cell.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Your data source methods are doing way too much work. It won't be fast enough, and the number and order of items must remain fixed, so there's no reason to rebuild the data model on each call.

Comment: I was just going through it - no idea why I decided to filter in numberOfRowsInSection either.

Answer (score 1):

@Duncan is right about one array. You have one array of dictionaries.
Now You need to also look at 
`func tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int)`
and 
`func numberOfSections(in: UITableView)`
If your are having numberOfSections == number of items in your array then indexpath.row will always be 0. I suspect that this might be the issue.

Comment: Damn, you're pretty much psychic - this is exactly it (numberOfRowsInSection == items in array). How can I fix this? What should it be instead in order to get the correct values in each cell/dictionary?

Comment: use `indexPath.section` instead of `indexPath.row`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... See my updated code above with my numberOfRowsInSection block.

Comment: Your `numberOfRows` in section should be depending on the `section` 
You have a generic filteredCount this won't work for tableView. 

So you need to decide for each section what is the number of rows you want to show. 
and then you'll be asked in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the cell you want to show for that section:row

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I misread your answer. The numberOfSections in my tableView is just 1 (return 1).

Comment: Then you dont even need to override it, its default to 1.

Comment: Ok, that said, I'm still getting the same value of the first cell's swapvalue for all of my dictionaries?

Comment: May be its having same value?
1. print your `NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.section];` and see if its got the right dictionary?